# cpp unit set up and teardown functions

Tags: c++, cppunit

can any one tell me how and when setup and teardown functions are called in cppunit.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

before every test function is run setup is called, and after each test function is run, teardown is called

Answer (score 1):

You use a `TestFixture` to isolate each test - [setUp and tearDown can be overridden](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.8.0/class_cpp_unit_1_1_test_fixture.html#_details) to perform test-specific initialization and termination logic.

> Detailed Description
>
> Wraps a test case with setUp and
>   tearDown methods. A TestFixture is
>   used to provide a common environment
>   for a set of test cases.
>
> To define a test fixture, do the
>   following:
>
> - implement a subclass of TestCase
> - the
>     fixture is defined by instance
>     variables
> - initialize the fixture state
>     by overriding setUp (i.e. construct
>     the instance variables of the fixture)
> - clean-up after a test by overriding
>     tearDown.

Comment: can u pls give me an example?

Comment: Did you follow the link?  There is an example directly under the summary text that I cut and paste.